How to know whether I should use DiD or Spatial RDD?
I'm quite new in econometrics. I want to study a nationwide policy change at the city-level. In year T-1, cities are divided in three zones (green, orange, red) depending on their tension on the housing market. Being in an orange or a red zone gives incentives for landlords to rent their houses. In year T, there is a massive re-zoning in the country. A lot of green cities became orange, and some orange cities became red. I want to study the effect of this policy change on immigration in the city in year T+1.
I'm not sure how I should do this, what approach should I use and what should be my treated and control groups. Can someone help me? Under what assumptions can my potential results be considered causal? Is this a DiD problem or a spatial RDD problem?
